# Retrieve Guild Owner Twitter/Twitch link for C# Discord.net

Tags: c#, twitter, discord, discord.net

I have what I think should be a crazy easy command to welcome users and then redirect them to the Guild Owners twitter. While I can have a static link I would prefer the bot pull the profile data on a guild owner level.

```
private async Task AnnounceUserJoined(SocketGuildUser user)
{
    var guild = user.Guild;
    var channel = guild.DefaultChannel;
    await channel.SendMessageAsync($"Welcome, {user.Mention}. Please follow OWNER on TWITTERLINK.");
}
```

I can get as far as reaching the guild owner with {Context.Guild.Owner. but then I lose the trail from there. But as the example I would like:

```
await channel.SendMessageAsync($"Welcome, {user.Mention}. Please follow {Context.Guild.Owner.TWITTERLINK}.");
```

Comment: where is "Context" exactly defined?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to get social media links from a user profile. The system you want may get a little spammy too.

Another alternative would be to let server owners set their links and have your bot save them somewhere.

If the person really wanted the owners social media they could just open up their profile or the owner could set up a designated channel for those links.